# Footnote does not appear

Tags: footnotes

As the title says.

```
\documentclass[reprint, prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

some text here.
\footnote{aaa}

\end{document}
```

This does not produce any footnote. It simply gives the above mentioned warning. (My main text is much larger but I just wanted to give an example. In the main text it actually also give a warning: Citation Note0 on page 1 is undefined.)

I have looked into other similar problems here in TS but nothing solving my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! According to the author guide for `revtex4`, footnotes appear in the bibliography by default. If you want them at the bottom of the page, pass `nofootinbib` to the class. `prb` puts footnotes at the start of the bibliography...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `revtex4-1` puts footnotes in the bibliography. This can be disabled with `nofootinbib` but `prb` puts them at the start of the bibliography anyway. So to get footnotes at the bottom of the page, you'd need:

```
\documentclass[reprint, nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

some text here.
\footnote{aaa}

\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes at bottom of page]

Otherwise, you need to typeset your bibliography for the notes to show up:

```
\documentclass[reprint, prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

some text here.
\footnote{aaa}

\bibliography{apssamp}

\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes in bib <code>prb</code> option]

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew about nonfootinbib but as you said it won't work unless prb is removed. Thank you.

Comment: @student1 You're welcome. Yes. It was adding `nofootinbib` and not getting a footnote which prompted me to look up `prb` ;).

Comment: Actually, it only works without prb, but without it the references now appear as [1] instead of 1 (superscript). What is the solution?

Comment: @student1 What makes it part of the abstract? I tried adding a new section with some more text and another note and that showed fine. (But if I use an abstract environment, I get neither abstract nor note.)

Comment: Sorry I modified my comment. The point is that, with prb option, only footnotes in abstract will appear at the bottom, all others at the bibliography. I guess that's how the journal wants it.

Comment: @student1 Yes, that's what `prb` does - more specifically, all notes are typeset at the start of the bibliography. If you are meant to use that option, I guess that's how they want the notes. That's why I said in my answer that you needed to remove that option as well to get `nofootinbib` working.